# Can someone resubmit a patent in 2005 on the same mechanism patent in 1990 or does it run out in 2010?

Tags: us4986791, us7517271

On patent US 4986791 A it appears the same person patented  a mechanism in 1990 then naming the mechanism something different in 2005 patentUS 7517271 B1 . So does the first patent end in 2010 or does the new one bind it untl 2025 ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the 2005 patent is quite different in scope from the 1990 patent. This is evident in the claims of the 2005 patent, which includes "means for supporting a wing flexibly affixed to said body portion". In contrast, the 1990 patent makes no reference to wings.

In any case, the 1990 patent protected the claimed invention until it expired (around 2003 it seems). Once it expired, the invention of the 1990 patent became "off patent", and was therefore free for anyone to use. Moreover, once off patent, could never be protected again. The 2005 patent appears to still be in force, but relates to a different invention from the 1990 one, so could not extend the protection initially given to the 1990 patent.